# Removing duplicates from each column and check every column in the chart

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I have a few thousand columns of data and I need to remove the duplicate records in each individual column before looking at the next column.  I have this code that was created when I recorded the Macro, but it's only doing the columns that I specifically entered, and I want it to continue looking at future columns until there is no more data.

```
Sub DUPLICATE()
'
' DUPLICATE Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$T$1:$T$12").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Columns("U:U").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$U$1:$U$12").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Columns("V:V").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$V$1:$V$12").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Columns("W:W").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$W$1:$W$12").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Columns("X:X").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$X$1:$X$12").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub DeleteDublicates()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Step 1
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).row, i)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next i

End Sub
```